# Twig Load error seen in DevMode but not in GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-datastore

Im seeing an exception in local Development Mode when trying to *load* using Twig (see below) that we dont see in the Live GAE.

My colleague also doesn't see it and yet we have the same dev set up
(although he runs on Mac)

The item it is failing on is an `ArrayList<ContactStatus>` where
`ContactStatus` is a simple enum (see below), here's the model
declaration

```
List<ContactStatus> contactStatuses = new ArrayList<ContactStatus>();
```

So as I understand it this should just work out of the box?

No `@Child` annotation etc needed? (indeed adding `@Embedded` seems to
cause issue35 : http://code.google.com/p/twig-persist/issues/detail?id=35)

When I run a debug session this seems to be failing because `ArrayList`
does not implement `Comparable` (since `Enum`s always do)

What are we doing wrong?!

**Versions**

- Java 7
- Twig 2.0-beta3
- AppEngine 1.6.2.1
- GWT 2.4.0

**Enum**

```
public enum ContactStatus implements IsSerializable, Serializable {
   Public, Secret, Blocked, Ignored;
}
```

**Exception we see in Dev Mode**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot compare [SimpleProperty value=[Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Blocked, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Blocked, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Blocked, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Blocked, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Blocked, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Blocked, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Blocked, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Blocked, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored] path=contactStatuses indexed=false] with [SimpleProperty value=[Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Blocked, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Blocked, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Blocked, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Blocked, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Blocked, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Blocked, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Blocked, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Blocked, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored, Ignored] path=contactStatuses indexed=false]
at com.google.code.twig.util.PropertyComparator.compare(PropertyComparator.java:23)
at com.google.code.twig.util.PropertyComparator.compare(PropertyComparator.java:7)
at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1188)
at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:531)
at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:334)
at java.util.TreeSet.addAll(TreeSet.java:312)
at com.google.code.twig.standard.StandardDecodeCommand.entityToInstance(StandardDecodeCommand.java:60)
at com.google.code.twig.standard.StandardDecodeCommand.keyToInstance(StandardDecodeCommand.java:127)
at com.google.code.twig.standard.StandardSingleTypedLoadCommand.keyToInstance(StandardSingleTypedLoadCommand.java:9)
at com.google.code.twig.standard.StandardSingleTypedLoadCommand.now(StandardSingleTypedLoadCommand.java:34)
at com.google.code.twig.standard.TranslatorObjectDatastore.load(TranslatorObjectDatastore.java:202)
at com.recruitmentlink.server.persistence.twig.TwigProfileImpl.getExistingCandidate(TwigProfileImpl.java:92)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a (super quick) reply from John Patterson on the issue and related code 'fix' that suppresses this unnecessary 'exception'

http://groups.google.com/group/twig-persist/browse_frm/thread/81b7d913a2ad37cc#

The issue only affects people using Java 7.

Since the GAE deployments are running Java 6, we don't see the issue in live.